# Python backwards for loop converted into java, not working

Tags: python, for-loop

I am so triggered by this. I am rewiriting a piece of python code into java. And my program has not been working. I have just found out why. It is the backwards for loop!

Python

```
for i in range(len(array) - 1, 2, -2):
```

MY written in java

```
for (int i = diff.size() - 1; i < 2; i = i - 2) {}
```

I've been pulling my hair out. Does anyone know what is wrong??!!!

Comment: In Java you should have `i > 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java version terminates when `i >= 2`, while the Python version terminates `i <= 2`. To fix, the loop condition should be `i > 2` for the Java version.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Such a small little mistake, I had to troubleshoot for hours. I am so careless.